# Adding few rows on single click and deleting the added rows on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Introduction:
I am new to JQuery and have a requirement wherein I need to implement a scenario of adding few rows on single click and deleting the added rows on double click.

Complete Scenario:
I have two tables in a page i.e. top parent table and below child table.
There are rows in parent table which needs to be clicked or double clicked.
Scenarios:
1)First Requirement is that on each single click on any of the rows of parent table, 5 rows should be added in the child table below i.e if there are 5 single clicks on row number 3 then total 25 rows should be added in the child table.
2)Second Requirement is that on each double click on any of the rows of parent table, all corresponding rows which were added on single click on the parent table's row should be deleted i.e. if row number 3 is double clicked all the 25 rows that were added corresponding to row number 3, in child table should be deleted.

Would need help in resolving the same.

```html
HTML Code:

<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 1455px;height:175px;" class="tree">
  <table class="boldtable" id="packagelisttable" style="width: 100%">

   <caption>
    <b style="font-size: 20px">Package List</b>
   </caption>
   <tr class="tableHeaderRow">
    <th class="columnHeader">Distributable Name</th>
    <th class="columnHeader">Version</th>
    <th class="columnHeader">Modality</th>
    <th class="columnHeader">Machine Name</th>
    <th class="columnHeader">Machine Type</th>
    <th class="columnHeader">Machine Version</th>
    <th class="columnHeader">Machine Version2</th>
  

    <th class="columnHeader">Last Registered By </th>
     <th class="columnHeader">Last Registered On </th>
   </tr>



   <tr class="lightData">
    <td class="columnHeader">Installer1</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">1</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">CT1</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">ABCD</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">Dell</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">1</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">1</td>


    <td class="columnHeader">User </td>
     <td class="columnHeader">11-10-2014 </td>


   </tr>

   <tr class="darkData">
       <td class="columnHeader">Installer2</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">1</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">CT1</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">PQRS</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">Dell</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">1</td>
    <td class="columnHeader">1</td>


    <td class="columnHeader">User </td>
     <td class="columnHeader">14-10-2014 </td>

   </tr>
  </table>



 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you attempted? What does your html look like?

Comment: @nish are you assigning a project to SO users, if not then show your code so that we can help you.

Comment: For future reference, you do not need to include tags in your title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: You only provided the html, what javascript/jquery attempts have you made. We can only answer questions with code issues, we are not a code writing service as indicated by Rohan.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#buttonid" ).click(function() {
```

//your code
});

```
$( "#buttonid" ).dblclick(function() {
```

//your code
});